# How to Solve "Cannot Import Name UNIX_TIMESTAMP" in PySpark?

Tags: pyspark

**Spark version 1.3.0**

**Python Version: 2.7.8**

I am trying to add a module called

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import unix_timestamp
```

However, it gives me an error:

```
ImportError: cannot import name SparkSession
```

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 0):

Your pyspark python library is incompatible with the Spark Version that you are using( version == 1.3.0) and SparkSession was introduced in 2.0.0.

Try updating Spark to latest version 2.3.0.